# Adding a 'blogs' prefix in the URL structure but only for blogs

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

In my site the blogs resolve as `%category%/%postname%` for now. However, I want the blog URLs to be `/blogs/%postname%`. I know I could go to Permalinks and add `blogs` as a prefix before `%postname%`. However, I also have custom post types. What this does is add the `blogs` prefix to the custom post types too. For example, I have a custom post type called `whitepapers` and all those URLs resolve to `whitepapers/%postname%` If I change the permalink structure as described above, it becomes `blogs/whitepapers/%postname%`.

How do I change the URL structure only for the `blogs` but let the custom post type be as they are?

Comment: You should just use the Permalink Settings page to set the permalink structure to `/blogs/%postname%` and for your custom post types, set the [`with_front` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#rewrite) to `false` to not include the `/blogs/` in the CPT posts' permalink.

Comment: @SallyCJ this helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @sally-cj mentioned in their comment, which is also the solution:

If you have set a custom permalink prefix (for example: `/blogs/%postname%/`) for your blog posts (which results in: `yoursite.com/blogs/lorem-ipsum-dolor`), but it also gets applied to your custom post types too (resulting in: `yoursite.com/blogs/customposttype/dolor-sit-amet`), the easiest and most conventional solution is to set the `with_front` argument to `false` on the CPTs.

If you are using ACF, you can find this in:
*Edit Post Type -> Advanced Settings -> URLs -> Front URL Prefix* (set this to `false`)